# How to identify or read nsf mails containing inline image

Tags: vb6, lotus-notes

I am trying to read mails programmatically in VB6. but i am unable to read mails containing inline images or HTML code like hyper link. Can anyone suggest me the way to read this type of mails. 

**EDIT:**
I am not getting any error message but

```
nsfDocument.GETITEMVALUE("Body")(0) returns only text.
```

images are not shown.

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try a third party API to help, such as the Midas Rich Text C++ API from Genii Software.  http://www.geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/MidasCPP

Or try the code examples shown on this site to gain access to the Notes Document in HTML form:  http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid4_gci1284906,00.html

Answer (score 0):

The GetItemValue method of the Document class returns rich-text item values as an array of strings, with all rich text styling removed. The "body" field in a Notes email is generally rich text. So, you should look into using the GetFirstItem method, instead. That will return a NotesRichTextItem object (for the body field). From that object, you can access the styling of the text, hyperlinks and file attachments, etc.  (I do not believe that you can access in-line images at all via the "back-end" COM classes - I think for that, you will need to drop down to use the C API classes).

Here's a quick sample of how to get a NotesRichTextItem handle:

```
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim rtitem As Variant
... get the document
Set rtitem = doc.GetFirstItem( "Body" )
If rtitem.Type = RICHTEXT Then
  .. work with rtItem
End If
```

Here is the doc page for the NotesRichTextItemClass:
http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/lotus/c2359850.nsf/2e73cbb2141acefa85256b8700688cea/dc72d312572a75818525731b004a5294?OpenDocument

And here is a starting point for the C API docs:
http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/nochargesearch.jsp?k=ALL&S_TACT=104CBW71&status=Active&q=Lotus+%22C+API%22